# Как вывести первые 2 значения из списка?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

У меня есть отфильтрованный выпадающий список. Я использую `selectOneMenu` для того чтобы отображались значения этого списка. К примеру их 10 000. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы в списке были видны только 50 первых значения. как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

заменила `selectOneMenu` на тег `autoComplete`, ведь у него есть атрибут `maxResult` да и по функционалу он намного обширнее